# how to use VBA ADODB connection to connect a closed workbook to get named range with character \

Tags: excel, vba, adodb, recordset

I have a workbook with a named range. Its name is A\B.

I would like to use Adodb connection and recordset to get the value of the named range. In order to do that, I need to first open recordset with that named range.

This method works fine on other named range if their names do not include \.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "D:\New.xlsx"
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open ConnectionString:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim namedRange As String
    namedRange = "A\B"
    'namedRange = Replace(namedRange, "\", ".")
    With rst
        .Open Source:="SELECT * FROM [" & namedRange & "]", _
              ActiveConnection:=cn, _
              CursorType:=adOpenStatic, _
              LockType:=adLockReadOnly, _
              Options:=adCmdText
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried to replace \ with other characters to test if it is caused by illegal character. The characters I tested are ~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]:";'<>?,./, space and double \.

I know nothing of SQL.

If someone can tell me how it can be done, it is very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: To avoid these errors, column names or whatever the query needs do not need to have special characters (that includes spaces in the headers names " "). A tirck for example would be to replace spaces by underscores "_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I apologize, I found a reference from Microsoft that clearly says, "don't do that": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/error-using-special-characters

ADODB driver is using MSAccess libraries so any rules you find for MSAccess apply to your situation. If you look at the section titled **Problem 3** where the slash character is cited, the answer is *"To work around this problem, do not use special characters."*

Try adding single quotes around the name:

```
With rst
    .Open Source:="SELECT * FROM ['" & namedRange & "']", _
          ActiveConnection:=cn, _
          CursorType:=adOpenStatic, _
          LockType:=adLockReadOnly, _
          Options:=adCmdText
End With
```

Comment: With single quotes, it throws same error code ( -2147217865).

Comment: I also tried the workaround suggested by your article quoted, which is enclosing the special characters in brackets ([]). Therefore I tried ([A\B]) , (A\B) , [A\B], but still error. So I guess that is the answer. Thank you for your help.